# Querying two tables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to query two different tables just, to see if there is one match. I have done a lot of research on how to do this and all I keep seeing is using the join clause. But I am not looking for a match between two tables. I just need to query both tables and see if there is one row with a match.

This is the code I'm using.

```
     $query = " SELECT id,account_type,email, password  FROM client
              WHERE email = ?
              UNION
            SELECT id,account_type,email, password  FROM freelancers
            WHERE email = ?  ";


    $email = $this->input->post("email");

    $result = $this->db->query($query, [$email]);

    // Just check if first there is an email that exists the  database
    if($result -> num_rows() == 1)  {
      //Do something
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by " I am not looking for a match between two tables. I just need to query both tables and see if there is one row with a match." Are you saying that you don't need only a match by email field you want all the columns to match? You also need to be more specific on how the wanted result needs to look like.

Comment: The question does not appear to relate to codeigniter or php, it is mysql specific. Do you **have** to run a single query for this? Why cannot you run separate queries for each table and handle results in php?

Comment: @despina Sorry I said that incorrectly. I am trying to run a query on both tables and to see if get one email match.

Comment: @B-and-P No I don't have to run a single query. I could have it in two separate queries. Just want make my code  more simple.  .

Comment: If you are going to use alot of these types of relationships, you should look at using an ORM to make life easier for yourself.

Comment: `$this->db->join("freelancers f", "true"); $query = $this->db->get('client c');` It's more a workaround than a solution but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a subquery:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE email = (SELECT email FROM freelancers WHERE email = ?)";
$email = $this->input->post("email");
$result = $this->db->query($query, array($email));
```